# Google Login issue for react native after uploading in the Google Play Store

Tags: google-signin

I am using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin module for google login. Google Login is working fine in the debug mode and also it is working fine in the signed apk, but while i upload in the play store by generating the aab file and download the apk after publishing it.Then i am checking the google login not working.

I am finding the solution on this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In google play console go to your app and click on Setup in that App signin.

[image]

Now copy that SHA-1 key and pest it in your firebase project setting add this.